# search a pattern in column and only keep the pattern in R

Tags: r

I have a column called fruits i.e "`apples [8]; bananas [102], pineapple [4000], total`" I only want to grade the string that starts with `[...]` and create a new column called code. So my new column would be `[8], [102], [4000]`, AND THE last row would be na if there is no [..]

My code seems to be doing the reverse  `noc$CODE <- gsub("\\s\\[.*\\]","[.*\\]",noc$Name)`

Comment: do you want the brackets in the new column?

Comment: how will the code change if I want to assign a [99999] to all variables without any [...].  i.e. our output should be [8], [102], [4000] and [99999]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the brackets in your vector/df, then

```
 gsub("[\\[\\]]", "", regmatches(vec, gregexpr("\\[.*?\\]", vec)))
[1] "[8]"          "[102]"        "[4000]"       "character(0)"
```

and if you don't want the brackets:

```
unlist(str_match_all(vec, "(?<=\\[).+?(?=\\])"))
[1] "8"    "102"  "4000"
```

***EDIT: Based on Question***

```
v <- data.frame(vec) %>% 
mutate(bracketed = gsub("[\\[\\]]", "", regmatches(vec, gregexpr("\\[.*?\\]", vec))), 
       bracketed_adj = if_else(bracketed == "character(0)", '[99999]', bracketed))
```

I would do it after that way it doesn't interfere or do anything hinky (technical term) to the output.

Comment: ```bracketed_adj = if_else(bracketed == character(0), '[99999]', bracketed)```  this code doesn't work it's not changing the zero character to [9999] in the new vector

Comment: @user15032839, corrected. The `character(0)` is a character in and of itself. So we need to reference the string version: `bracketed == "character(0)"`